# How to access basic user information for "Private Users" on Instagram API?

Tags: ios, instagram-api

I am writing an application and need to read basic Instagram user info such as username, #posts, #followers and etc. This works well for public users but for private users returns:

```
{
  "meta":
  {
      "code":400,
      "error_message":"you cannot view this resource",
      "error_type":"APINotAllowedError"
  }
```

}

Let's say I am signed in as user A, and we want to show information from User B which is private to user A (user B also authorized my application to access it's basic info). I am using the following end point to read user B information:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<userB_ID>/?access_token=<myAccessToken>
```

Am I missing something? or should I use different end point?

**Update (Solution #1)**

It seems one solution to fix this is to use Query end point. I was trying to manage all my work with Instagram user IDs (not usernames) but it seems I have to use usernames for the query. Is there a way to use query with user ID?
Here is what it looks like:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=<UserB_Username>&client_id=<myClientID>
```

Answer (score 0):

if `<myAccessToken>` is to get user A's info, you can't get User B's info with it. If you have a backend to this app, then you can store different access tokens for each user, and make the call with the appropriate access token, and feed the info to the app through your own API.